# Firefox error for signalR, but does not effect anything

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I get the 2 following errors in firefox when using signalR and I do not know why:

```
Timestamp: 10/15/2012 3:53:48 PM
Error: The connection to http://localhost:81/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionId=84a7f433-0cc8-4baf-93e9-d4c3ca968466&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22Chat%22%7D%5D&tid=7 was interrupted while the page was loading.
Source File: http://localhost:81/Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.3.min.js
Line: 9
```

and

```
Timestamp: 10/15/2012 3:53:50 PM
Error: no element found
Source File: http://localhost:81/signalr/abort?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionId=84a7f433-0cc8-4baf-93e9-d4c3ca968466
Line: 1
```

Everything seems to work fine with SignalR and my application works as expected across all browsers, but I just get these errors in firefox only.  Any ideas?

Comment: Might be related to the second error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975929/firefox-error-no-element-found

Comment: @anthonypliu, did you ever get this one solved?

Comment: Also having this issue.... fresh pretty much blank SignalR install with just a $.connection.hub.start()