# Convert PHP nested array to XML tree structure

Tags: php, xml

I have following array in PHP and I want to convert it equivalent XML.

```
$data = array("VitalParameters"=>array(
                    "Details"=>array(
                        "PID"=>1234,
                        "OPID"=>1345
                    ),
                    "Parameters"=>array(
                        "HR"=>112,
                        "SPO2"=>0
                )));
```

Following XML tree structure which I expected

```
<VitalParameters>
    <Details>
      <PID>1234</PID>
      <OPID>1345</OPID>
    </Details>
    <Parameters>
      <HR>112</HR>
      <SPO2>0</SPO2>
    </Parameters>
</VitalParameters>
```

I tried many things but no luck. If any more information required just comment I will give additional information.

Comment: Down voted please comment what you want or give suggession for downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution like following code

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
$data = array(
    "Details" => array(
        "PID" => "1234","OPID" => "1345"
    ),"Parameters" => array(
        "HR" => "112","SPO2" => "0"
    )
);

$domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
/* create the root element of the xml tree */
$xmlRoot = $domtree->createElement("VitalParameters");
/* append it to the document created */
$xmlRoot = $domtree->appendChild($xmlRoot);

foreach ($data as $key=>$value)
{
    $currentElement= $domtree->createElement($key);
    $currentElement= $xmlRoot->appendChild($currentElement);
    if(is_array($value))
    {
        foreach ($value as $k=>$v)
        {
            $currentElement->appendChild($domtree->createElement($k,$v));
        }
    }
}

/* get the xml printed */
echo $domtree->saveXML();
```

**Output**

```
<VitalParameters>
  <Details>
    <PID>1234</PID>
    <OPID>1345</OPID>
  </Details>
  <Parameters>
    <HR>112</HR>
    <SPO2>0</SPO2>
  </Parameters>
</VitalParameters>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Array2XML (http://www.lalit.org/lab/convert-php-array-to-xml-with-attributes) this has worked for me.

```
$data = array(
  "Details" => array(
    "PID" => 1234,
    "OPID" => 1345
  ),
  "Parameters" => array(
    "HR" => 112,
    "SPO2" => 0
));


$xml = Array2XML::createXML('VitalParameters', $data)->saveXML();

echo $xml;
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VitalParameters>
  <Details>
    <PID>1234</PID>
    <OPID>1345</OPID>
  </Details>
  <Parameters>
    <HR>112</HR>
    <SPO2>0</SPO2>
  </Parameters>
</VitalParameters>
```

Comment: I tried but give me error like `XML Parsing Error: no element found`

Comment: Are you using firefox? Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975929/firefox-error-no-element-found.

Comment: In google chrome also not work and I am getting `This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.`

Answer (score 0):

This should get you on the right track, probably needs some tuning though (especially in regards to keys aswell as checking if $arr is an array/object in the first place... this was just to show you how to recursively iterate them and print the data).

Also, this snippet does not support XML attributes in any way.

```
<?php
$data = array("VitalParameters"=>array(
                    "Details"=>array(
                        "PID"=>1234,
                        "OPID"=>1345
                    ),
                    "Parameters"=>array(
                        "HR"=>112,
                        "SPO2"=>0
                )));

function ArrayToXML($arr, $depth = 0, $maxDepth = 2)
{
    $retVal = "";
    foreach($arr as $key => $value)
    {
        $retVal .= "<" . $key . ">";

        $type = gettype($value);
        switch($type)
        {
            case "array":
            case "object":
                if ($depth < $maxDepth)
                    $retVal .= ArrayToXml($value, $depth+1, $maxDepth);
                else
                    $retVal .= $type; // Depth >= MaxDepth, not iterating here
                break;
            case "boolean":
                $retVal .= $value ? "true" : "false";
                break;
            case "resource":
                $retVal .= "Resource";
            case "NULL":
                $retVal .= "NULL";
            default:
                $retVal .= $value;
        }
        $retVal .= "</" . $key . ">\n";
    }
    return $retVal;
}

echo ArrayToXML($data);
?>
```

Output:

```
<VitalParameters><Details><PID>1234</PID>
<OPID>1345</OPID>
</Details>
<Parameters><HR>112</HR>
<SPO2>0</SPO2>
</Parameters>
</VitalParameters>
```

Comment: Can I set header like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` because I want to save file as XML

Comment: Your code give correct output but do not display header as I mentioned above comment so how I can set header?

Comment: You should be able to send the `Content-Type` using PHPs `header()` function. As I mentioned though: This is not a fully fleshed XML implementation. Attributes won't work, keys are missing sanity-checks and there's probably a lot more to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think - this is must be more simple:

```
function arrayToXML($arr){

  $s = "";

  foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    if(is_array($v)){$v = arrayToXML($v);}
    $s .= "<{$k}>{$v}</{$k}>";
  }

  return $s;}
```