# Javascript/AJAX/PHP error: No element found and unable to write to a file

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I've been struggling with this error for a couple of days now. Searched stackoverflow and other web sources but so far no luck.

The code is fairly simple. I have a test.html file which calls a saveFile.php. However, I have two problems. 
1) In Firefox, I keep getting a "no element found" error. Don't see this problem in Chrome. 
2) Even though saveFile.php seems to be getting called, it does not write a file as it should. This is the case with both browsers and I really need to be able to write to a file.

This is the test.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>IIDS: Basic Boilerplate</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

hello world

<script src="../components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "saveFile.php",
            //url: "http://localhost/~usesr1/mywork/saveFile.php",
            //dataType: "json",
            data: 'test',
            success:function(text) {
                    console.log(text);

            },
            error: function(xhr, status) {
                    alert("unable to save data");
            },

    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the saveFile.php:

```
<?php

    $tdata = "hello world this is a test";
    $testf = fopen('hello123', 'w+');
    fwrite($testf, $tdata);
    fclose($testf);

    echo "yes";
    // header("Content-Type: text/plain"); Got this from another stackoverflow question, but this didn't fix the problem.
    exit();

?>
```

Both files are in the same directory under ~/public_html. I gave 777 permissions to the directory. This is a machine running Ubuntu 14.04.

In saveFile.php, tried "GET" instead of "POST" but no luck again.

I'm stuck and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: This question is not a duplicate of the one linked in the comments. The main difference is that I am not able to get my php to write to a file. I don't necessarily care about the "no element found" error as long as the php script is able to write to file. I only decided to include that error in this post because I thought it might be relevant to my real problem.

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: what happens if you simply access the saveFile.php route in your browser? does the file get created?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your PHP file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Did you search for "firefox no element found"? I found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/976200/4137738 which says: use

`header('Content-Type: text/plain');`

and Firefox will not try to parse the response as XML, and there should be no error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox error 'no element found'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975929/firefox-error-no-element-found)

Comment: Jay Blanchard, I get a 200 response code. I think that means it's okay.

Comment: Cristik, Yes I am able to access that jquery.js file from my browser

Comment: wmk, If you noticed in my code above in my original post, I already have that line - header("Content-Type: text/plain") - in there with a comment that I found it on stackoverflow. The reason I have it commented out above is that it didn't seem to make any difference.  Also, unlike the post you've linked to, my main problem is that my php script is not writing to a file.

Comment: Kris Zani, I tried accessing saveFile.php  in my browser but it does not create any file. :-(  However, if I run the php script directly from the command line, it works - it creates a file.

Comment: Have you tried using fopen with a path? Example - $testf = fopen('/tmp/hello123', 'w+');  - change /tmp/ to the path you want to write to.

Comment: Jay Blanchard, I added the error reporting as you suggested but don't see anything.

Comment: thirtyish, I already did that and that didn't work. I've tried all combinations and workarounds but no luck :-(

Comment: Kris Zani, I dug a bit deeper and it turns out that my PHP wasn't running correctly via the server. I could still run local scripts from the command line. I think this probably has to do with a large number of Ubuntu updates that I did this week after having gone without updating for a few weeks. So, now the php file writes a file to disk and also, for some reason, the "no element found" also seems to have disappeared. Double win. :) Thanks for getting me started in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify when the AJAX event has to happen.

Since you want it to fire when you open the page add the $(document).ready function and it will fire when document has finished loading. Or you can bind it for example to a `.click()` event of a button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "saveFile.php",
                data: 'test',
                success:function(text) {
                        console.log(text);   
                },
                error: function(xhr, status) {
                    alert("unable to save data");
                },
        });
    });
</script>
```