# Nginx cut-off Content-Type header in responce id http status is 204

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-204

I have following configuration nginx server that proxy requests to tomcat server:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
}
```

This works fine, but in firefox we have issue like in this: [Firefox error 'no element found'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975929/firefox-error-no-element-found/976200#976200)

Why nginx cut-off content-type header, and how to prevent him from doing it?

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: no. as i remember this is true only for PUT requests. So we replace PUT with POST.